# Intergration Supersized

Tags: jquery, html, fullscreen

I got these two scripts running. One is a script the works with supersized. The other script is for the fading of the other images. The purpose of the script is to fade in backgroundimages based on mouse over behaviour on list items. The background images have to be full screen and maintain the aspect ratio. The problem is that the images that are fading in don't get effected by the supersized script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
        jQuery(function($){         
            $.supersized({
                slides  :   [{image : '01.jpg', title : '01'},
                             {image : '02.jpg', title : '02'},
                             {image : '03.jpg', title : '03'},
                             {image : '04.jpg', title : '04'},]
            });
        });     
    </script>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function()
 {
function fadeImage (img) {
    $("#div").stop(true).animate ({ opacity: 0 }, 'slow', function () {
        $(this).css ('background-image', img).animate ({ opacity: 1 }, 'slow');
    });
}
var colorOrig="url(01.jpg)";
$("#first").hover(
function() {
fadeImage ('url(02.jpg)');
}, function() {
fadeImage (colorOrig);
});
$("#second").hover(
function() {
fadeImage ('url(03.jpg)');

}, function() {
fadeImage (colorOrig);
});
$("#third").hover(
function() {
fadeImage ('url(04.jpg)');
}, function() {
fadeImage (colorOrig);
});
});
```